# trying to stream the other user video but unable to

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets

I'm not able to see the other user video, only my video keep showing in both the video element.
do i have to write the peer code as well using simple-peer library or should socket is enough to make connection and navigation.getUserMedia api is enough to run two videos.

```
    const [remoteStreams, setRemoteStreams] = useState([]); // Array to store remote video streams
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]); // Array to store user information
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]); // Array to store chat messages
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(""); // State variable to manage the chat input message

    // Refs for referencing and accessing specific elements
    const localStreamRef = useRef(null); // Ref to hold the local media stream
    const localVideoRef1 = useRef(null); // Ref to the first local video element
    const localVideoRef2 = useRef(null); // Ref to the second local video element

useEffect(() => {
        // Join the room
        const roomName = "exampleRoom";
        console.log("user joined", roomName); // Log that the user has joined the room

        // Function to update the user list when users change
        const handleUserUpdate = (updatedUsers) => {
            setUsers(updatedUsers); // Update the 'users' state with the new user list
        };

        // Function to handle new incoming messages
        const handleNewMessage = (newMessage) => {
            setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessage]); // Add the new message to the 'messages' state
        };

        // Emit a socket event to join the specified room
        socket.emit("joinRoom", roomName, (response) => {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("Joined room successfully"); // Log that joining the room was successful

                // Set up socket listeners for updates from the server
                socket.on("hostVideo", handleUserUpdate); // Listen for user updates
                socket.on("receiveMessage", handleNewMessage); // Listen for new messages
            }
        });

        // Handle WebRTC video streaming
        // Request access to the user's camera and microphone for video streaming
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }) // Specify desired media types
            .then((stream) => {
                // Once the stream is obtained, update the local media stream reference
                localStreamRef.current = stream;

                // Set the stream as the source object for the first local video element
                const localVideo1 = localVideoRef1.current;
                if (localVideo1) localVideo1.srcObject = stream;

                // Set the stream as the source object for the second local video element
                const localVideo2 = localVideoRef2.current;
                if (localVideo2) localVideo2.srcObject = stream;

                // Emit the local stream to the server to share it with others
                socket.emit("sendLocalStream", roomName, stream);

                // Handle the reception of remote streams from other users
                socket.on("receiveRemoteStream", (remoteStream) => {
                    // Update the list of remote streams
                    setRemoteStreams((prevStreams) => [
                        ...prevStreams,
                        remoteStream,
                    ]);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error accessing user media:", error);
            });
```